# Clearing WebView Cache from withing QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I open website with QDeclarativeView and use JavaScript to load next pages in same view.

After each website loaded, my program occupy 20mb more of memory. How do i clean the cache or otherwise release the memory after new website is loaded?

I tried:

> decView->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myEngine", decView->engine());

and then in qml

> myEngine.clearComponentCache()

but i get

> TypeError: Result of expression 'myEngine.clearComponentCache' [undefined] is not a function.

What i should do?

EDIT: here is what i got sofar:
aws.cpp

```
void Aws::openQMLWindowSlot(){
   QDeclarativeView *decView= new QDeclarativeView();
   decView->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myAws",this);
   decView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/inc/firstqml.qml"));
   decView->show();
}

void Aws::clearCacheQMLSlot(){

//HERE I GOT PROBLEM
}
```

firstqml.qml

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import QtWebKit 1.0
WebView {

    id: webView
    objectName: "myWebView"
    url:"http://example.com"
    onLoadFinished: {myAws.clearCacheQMLSlot();}
}
```

Comment: There us `gc()` method in javascript, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, i tried webView.evaluateJavaScript("gc();"); and gc(), both with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two reasons why your code doesn't work as intended. First, to be able to access slots and invokable methods of `QObject` descendants, you have to [register](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeengine.html#qmlRegisterType) them:

```
qmlRegisterType<QDeclarativeEngine>("MyApp", 1, 0, "QDeclarativeEngine");
```

And second, `QDeclarativeEngine::clearComponentCache` is neither a slot nor an [invokable method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE), so it would still not work. It is simply impossible to call normal C++ methods from QML.

What you actually have to do is to implement an own `QObject` based class wrapping the call to `QDeclarativeEngine::clearComponentCache` in a slot, registering the class like above, set an instance of that class as an context property like you did with the declarative engine and finally call the slot from QML.

Comment: Thanks for answer.I'm setting 'this' with             `decView->engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myAws",this);` in same place i create decView, so all public slots are exposed to qml file but how i make a call to `QDeclarativeEngine::clearComponentCache`in that slot?

Comment: Just store a pointer to the declarative view or to the engine in your class as a member variable and call the method on it.